# Hibernate and PostgreSQL - checking if a collection passed in setParameterList is empty

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, postgresql

I'm building a query where I want to pass a collection as a parameter:

```
List<String> items = new LinkedList();
//adding optional items
Query query = s.getNamedQuery("myQueryName").setParameterList("item", items);
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT i from Item i
//... not important things
WHERE ( i.name in (:item) )
```

but I want to make it optional, so the items list could be empty. But when it's empty, I get an exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected end of subtree
```

So I tried to use some functions like:

```
SELECT i from Item i
//... not important things
WHERE ( (:item) is null or i.name in (:item) )

SELECT i from Item i
//... not important things
WHERE ( (:item) is empty or i.name in (:item) )

SELECT i from Item i
//... not important things
WHERE ( size(:item)=0 or i.name in (:item) )
```

but none of it seems to work. How can I solve this problem and checking if an item name is in a list only if the list is not empty?

Comment: can you build the query by checking the items empty or not? e.g. build the query with/without "i.name in(:item)" part?

Comment: well, it could solve the problem, but what I wanted to achieve is to get it work in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's, IMHO, a design problem in SQL, that is of course also present in HQL, since it directly translates to SQL.

There is no easy solution to deal with that in HQL. The easiest, and most efficient thing to do, is to check the list before even generating and executing the query.

In many cases, you just need to do:

```
if (items.isEmpty()) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

In your case, I would use a criteria query (or another API used to dynamically build queries), and build the query dynamically:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Item.class, i);
...
if (!items.isEmpty()) {
    c.add(Restrictions.in("i.name", items));
}
return c.list();
```

Comment: Well, my query is much more complicated and in this case I cannot use a criteria query. So do you think that the only way to do it is to build two queries and execute the right one depending on a list size?

Comment: I don't know of any other way.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a value to the list that you know will never return true.  For example, let's say you have a list of integers and you want to see if an ID is contained in the list.  You could add '-1' to the list and it should work the way you want.  For your string example, just add a random string that will never occur.

Something like:

```
List<String> items = new LinkedList();
items.add("**BLAHBLAH_YO_MAMMA_SO_SLEAZY_SHE_ALWAYS_RETURN_TRUE**");
//add optional items
Query query = s.getNamedQuery("myQueryName").setParameterList("item", items);
```